# IISReset... the safe way?

Tags: exchange-2003

I've read a few articles as to why performing an IISReset is not safe as it doesn't completely save XYZ (can't remember exactly what now).

What is the safest alternative to IISReset?

I ask this because I did an IISReset on one of our servers on the weekend and the exchange store service froze in the 'stopping' state - ended up fixing it by killing the store.exe process and restarting the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, iisreset doesn't stop the Exchange Information Store - only the SMTP service.

You could try iisreset /noforce or you could fire up IIS Manager on the server and from the menu choose *Restart Internet Services on [server name]* (which for all I know, could just be doing iisreset /noforce in the background).

I have to bounce IIS on our Exchange server periodically (3rd party app keeps crashing) and personally, I use the GUI as I seem to have more luck with it.

Comment: I will try the /noforce switch when I next need to, thanks!
I read a recommendation elsewhere whereby a net stop and net start was recommended but I can't remember the services they stopped - I didn't think that this was the best solution as I believe there are many services dependant on IIS.